# Error: Could not find MIME for Buffer <null>

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I tried to check any Url but for some image file get above Error .

Below are the used code  if you guide mw

```
    const image_url = req.query.image_url.toString(); 
     if(!image_url){
      res.status(400).send("Image URL not Defined"); 
    }
    const Image_Filtered = await filterImageFromURL(image_url);
    res.contentType('image/jpeg');
    res.status(200).send(Image_Filtered,() => {
      deleteLocalFiles([Image_Filtered]);
    });
```

Comment: The issue is likely being thrown in `filterImageFromURL()`, which you're not providing.

Comment: This error happen when through a link with jpg while with a normal Image jpeg work fines

Comment: So again, the issue seems to be with `filterImageFromURL()` which we can't say anything about.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set mimeType in header like this :

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
```

Comment: I tried it but still the same error .